# Can we develop ios15 apps on MacBook pro mid 2012, can we get developer account to download latest MacOS & Xcode on older mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-catalina, macos-monterey

I have MacBook pro mid 2012 , running Catalina OS, with Xcode 12.4

I need to get latest MacOS(Montrey) & Xcode 13, to develop apps using iOS 15 for the latest devices available in the market. I am unable to use iOS 15 functions to build apps.

How can I achieve that?

Will getting developer account let me install latest OS and Xcode on MacBook?

Please guide.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, and if you get the Premium developer account, your MacBook pro mid 2012 turns into a brand new M1! — Sorry, that was a silly joke. But seriously, no kind of membership or license will change the capabilities of your hardware. The way to do that is purchase hardware that has the desired capabilities.

Comment: Maybe you can: https://osxdaily.com/2021/11/30/installing-macos-monterey-on-unsupported-macs/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not. From April 2022, apps submitted for the app store will need to [be on Xcode 13](https://xcodereleases.com/). The minimum macOS version for [Xcode 13.x is macOS 11.3+](https://xcodereleases.com/) that runs on [MacBook Pro: Late 2013 and newer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur).